# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb, .net-core, signalr

I am attempting to collect data from a Mongo database and return the data to a SignalR Javascript client. I am using .net core.

The data returned is a List. The code on the server hits a breakpoint and when I step through the code, it returns the list of data as I expect. The SignalR client, however, throws an exception...

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed
```

For kicks, I changed the Mongo query to return a count() from the list and that worked like a charm. I also changed the hub to return an empty list (without querying Mongo) and that also worked... I have a feeling Mongo is the issue. This is my first project using MongoDB.

Here is my client code (Javascript)

```
this.hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("/api")
  .build();    
this.hub.start({transport: 'webSockets'}).then(() => {
  console.log("STATE", this.hub.state); // state is "Connected" at this point.
  this.hub.invoke("GetData").then((data) => {
    console.log(data); // We never reach this line
  });
});
```

On the server, I have this code in my hub:

```
    public List<Data> GetData() {
        return this.GetService().GetData();
        // return new List<Data>(); // If I replace the lines above with this, it works??? Has to be MongoDB?
    }
```

My server-side service code is:

```
public List<Data> GetData() {
     MongoClient client = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase"));
     IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase");
     IMongoCollection<Data> data = database.GetCollection<Data>("Data");
     return data
        .Find(t => !t.Deleted)
        .ToList();
```

}

I am wondering if Mongo is somehow trying to change the data as it streams back to the client.

I am converting the IMongoCollection to a List before sending it through SignalR to the client.

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it works now after I made the following changes:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(options =>
{
    options.ServerStickyMode = Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServerStickyMode.Required;
});
```